# Troubleshoot gcc installation

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile

I have the following setup:

I don't have root priviliges, so I usually build my stuff from source to $HOME/.local

System is Debian 3.16.84-1

I wanted to update my gcc installation.
there's version 4.9.2 installed systemwide, and I installed version 8.4.0 some years ago for local user.
Now I try to install the current version 11.2.0
My first try was to do it with version 8.4.0

the following error occurs when running make:

```
if [ x"-fpic" != x ]; then \
  gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g  -I. -I../.././libiberty/../include  -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wc++-compat -Wstrict-prototypes -pedantic  -D_GNU_SOURCE  -fpic ../.././libiberty/floatformat.c -o
 pic/floatformat.o; \
else true; fi
*** Error in `/home/user/.local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.4.0/cc1': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000002a19c70 ***
../.././libiberty/floatformat.c: In function ‘floatformat_to_double’:
../.././libiberty/floatformat.c:547:2: internal compiler error: Aborted
  dto = ldexp (1.0, exponent);
  ^~~
```

using 8.9.2 I get a similar error:

```
if [ x"-fpic" != x ]; then \
  gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g  -I. -I../.././libiberty/../include  -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wc++-compat -Wstrict-prototypes -pedantic  -D_GNU_SOURCE  -fpic ../.././libiberty/floatformat.c -o pic/floatformat.o; \
else true; fi
*** Error in `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/cc1': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000003626810 ***
*** Error in `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/cc1': malloc(): memory corruption: 0x0000000003626850 ***
gcc: internal compiler error: Aborted (program cc1)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.9/README.Bugs> for instructions.
Makefile:804: recipe for target 'floatformat.o' failed
```

I have the feeling there's a more general underlying problem somewhere but I have no idea how to troubleshoot.
I can post full logs if needed.

Comment: Debian 8 jessie: Yes, very strange, older gcc builds are no longer working.The default gcc-4.9.2 behaves well (But cannot build gcc-11, gcc-8 can) ... Compilers built with / for Debian 7 and/or Ubuntu 16.04 (e.g. gcc 7.3 / 9.3) are expected to work OK too. They fail https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xVEATaYAwqvseBzYxKDzJoZ4-Hc_XOJm?usp=sharing → A new `gcc85-c++_8.5.0-8LOCAL_amd64.tar.xz` is included now. Unpack in `/home/user/.local/`. ...... (Runs a gcc-11.2.0 build now https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_s26Qj-klCvzP_azCZCaYiBc7n6OdAKC?usp=sharing )

Comment: The new build of gcc 8.5 compiles gcc-11.2.0 with no errors.

Comment: @KnudLarsen
Thanks. I tried to build 8.5 now but get the same error with the floatformat.c file.

I found something however, that's not right and I don't know how to fix:
There's /usr/bin/gcc (v4.9) and
/home/user/.local/bin/gcc.   

`which gcc` evaluates to
`/home/user/.local/bin/gcc`

however `gcc --version` shows  v4.9   
`/home/user/.local/bin/gcc --version` shows 8.4

I can't figure out why gcc calls version 4.9 and not 8.4

Comment: You actually don't have to build any gcc. Download `gcc85-c++_8.5.0-8LOCAL_amd64.tar.xz` and unpack anywhere. Create gcc, g++ links ... and use. .... `gcc11.2-c++_11.2.0-8LOCAL_amd64.tar.xz` : The same . https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xVEATaYAwqvseBzYxKDzJoZ4-Hc_XOJm?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you very much @KnudLarsen. The error is now gone. Small hint for others: At least in the file `lib64/libstdc++.la` you have to manually adjust the  `libdir` variable.
I now run into an error related to make, probably also because it's heavily outdated. Do you happen to have a magic local tar file for `build-essentials` as well?

Comment: I got no errors with Debian 8 jessie, see my build methods https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_s26Qj-klCvzP_azCZCaYiBc7n6OdAKC?usp=sharing